# Lua: command lines parameters are nil on windows 8.1

Tags: command-line, parameters, lua, command

I run the Lua script using command line:

```
scipt.lua arg
```

But when I want to print the value arg1 in script:

```
print(arg[1])
```

Result is nil.

When I try to run it like:

```
lua script.lua arg
```

It returns not recognized command for windows.
What I am doing wrong? How can I get parameters from command line?

Comment: What version of lua is this?

Comment: I guess it's Lua 5.3.0

Comment: Do you get the result you expect if you use `print(arg[0])` in your script?

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any problem with your example. Since you are able to run this command, but do not get any arguments passed, it's possible that whatever script registered the association, didn't use the syntax for passing arguments. You can find the registered association and check the command to make sure it includes `%*` to pass all the parameters to the script.

You can find where the executable is by using `where lua.exe` command and then call that executable directly from the command line to see if it works.

Comment: To add to Paul's answer, registry entries of interest are: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Lua\Shell\Open\Command` and `HKCLASSES_ROOT\.lua`. For the former make sure there's `(Default) REG_SZ C:\lua-5.1.5\lua.exe "%1" %*` and the latter `(Default) REG_SZ Lua`. If they're missing just add them and of course adjust the paths as appropriate for your config.